# How do i convert a .text table to pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-science

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEVsz.png)

How do I convert this to a panadas dataframe. I get the error code:(ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 37, 5)) when I used pd.DataFrame() command.

Comment: Can you share the url `pd.read_html` reads? I assume there is a multi-index row that messes things up.

Comment: `pd.read_html` returns a list of dataframes even if there is only 1 dataframe. So `df = pd.read_html(...)[0]` or `df, = pd.read_html(...)` should work and the dataframe will be available in `df`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see you posted your code, tried to replicate the issue referring to the problem you mentioned along with the data you looking to fetch as described in the [hyperlink image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEVsz.png). Successfully converted into panda data frame by following scripts, check it if it helps resolve your issue.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

#Creating the http GET request
#As per your "enter image description here", looks like you are fetching "Cases by State"
r = requests.get('https://covid19.ncdc.gov.ng/')

#Getting the table and converting the results to data frame df
df = pd.read_html(r.text)

#Confirming the data frame results
df
```